# Unwrapping function types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

is there a way to unwrap the following type in Haskell?

```
newtype Rand a = Rand(StdGen -> (a , StdGen))
```

I've got a function which returns this type and another one which I'd like to use the 'a' value from the returned function, but I can't figure out how to extract the value.

Comment: Haskell has pattern matching. E.g. you can define your function (say `f`) as `f Rand x = [something in terms of x]`. There are more advanced pattern-matching ways; someone will answer. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you write:

```
newtype Rand a = Rand(StdGen -> (a , StdGen))
```

It's important to know *what* you're writing.

In this case, `newtype` is equivalent to `data` (the only caveat being `newtype` is more efficient). So, we could alternatively write the type definition like so:

```
data Rand a = Rand (StdGen -> (a, StdGen))
```

Piece by piece:

```
Type constructor
      |              ..-- Type parameter
     \|/       ..--''
      '   .--''
data Rand a = Rand (StdGen -> (a, StdGen))
               .   '---------------------'
              /|\              |
               |               '- Wrapped data
     Data constructor
```

First, let's look at a simpler example:

```
data Sum = Sum Int
```

Annotated:

```
Type constructor
      |
     \|/
      '
data Sum = Sum Int
            .  '-'
           /|\  '--- Wrapped data
            |
     Data constructor
```

To be clearer, we'll differentiate the type (constructor) from the (data) constructor:

```
data SumType = SumCon Int
```

Now, how would we extract the `Int` held in a value `x :: SumType`?

The obvious choice is pattern matching:

```
getSum :: SumType -> Int
getSum (SumCon n) = n
```

And this works. But this is a pretty common (and trivial) thing to want to do - and to make it easier, 'record syntax' was introduced. This means we can rewrite our type like so:

```
data SumType = SumCon { getSum :: Int }
```

Now we don't have to write `getSum` manually any more -- the compiler will do it for us, meaning we can assume a function `getSum :: SumType -> Int` exists.

Now, let's go back to `Rand a`:

```
newtype Rand a = Rand (StdGen -> (a, StdGen))
```

We could either manually write:

```
getRand :: Rand a -> (StdGen -> (a, StdGen))
getRand (Rand f) = f
```

Or just let the compiler do it for us:

```
newtype Rand a = Rand { getRand :: StdGen -> (a, StdGen) }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have the data type

```
newtype Rand a = Rand (StdGen -> (a, StdGen))
```

The only way you can get an `a` out of it is by supplying a `StdGen` (remember, this is more or less an alias for `StdGen -> (a, StdGen)`):

```
runRand :: Rand a -> StdGen -> (a, StdGen)
runRand (Rand f) g = f g
```

To make it simpler, I would recommend instead defining `Rand` with record syntax:

```
newtype Rand a = Rand { runRand :: StdGen -> (a, StdGen) }
```

Where `runRand` will have the same type, but now it's all defined in one line for you.  If you want just the `a` value, then just use `fst`:

```
evalRand :: Rand a -> StdGen -> a
evalRand r g = fst $ runRand r g
```

Answer (score 1):

Just make it a named record....

```
newtype Rand a = Rand{ runRandom::(StdGen -> (a , StdGen)) }
```

then you can get it like this

```
runRandom x --returns the function
```

or use it like this

```
runRandom x gen
```

Answer (score 1):

You can match on the `Rand` constructor:

```
getRand :: Rand a -> (StdGen -> (a, StdGen))
getRand (Rand f) = f
```

You need an instance `StdGen` to be able to get a value of `a` from the resulting function. You can use `mkStdRandom` e.g.

```
genWith :: Rand a -> Int -> a
genWith (Rand f) = fst . f . mkStdGen
```